# Need MIB for corresponding VLAN CLI commands

Tags: command, snmp, command-line-interface, mib

Need MIB for below VLAN CLI commands. Any idea.?

• description
• default vlan-id
• default-vlan disable
• enable vlan-counters
• name
• show config
• show vlan
• tagged
• track ip
• untagged

Answer (score 0):

You have MIBs which support few of the mentioned objects but not all of them though.

show config, enable vlan counters are specific to implemention and there is no standard way of configuring them through SNMP .

qBridgeMIB will contain rest of the objects that you are looking for .